# Distribution function constraints from moments?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-distributions

Let $g(x,v)$, $(x,v)\in [0,\infty)\times [0,\infty) $ be an unknown function for which we have knowledge of the following moments/constraints:

$$\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\text{d} x \int_{v=0}^{\infty} \text{d}v  \, g(x,v) = 1$$
$$\rho(x) = \int_{v=0}^{\infty} \text{d} v \, g(x,v) \geq 0 $$
$$\frac{d \rho}{d x} \leq 0$$
$$g(x,v) = g(x,-v)$$
$$\int_{v=0}^{\infty} \text{d} v \, v g(x,v) = 0 , \forall x $$
$$\sigma^2(x) = \int_{v=0}^{\infty} \text{d} v \, v^2 g(x,v) \geq 0$$

In addition we may consider that $\sigma^2(x) < M$, where $M$ is some positive upper bound.

**My question**: 
Are these conditions sufficient for  $g(x,v) \geq 0$ in $ [0,\infty)\times [0,\infty) $ ? And if yes, can we prove it? Any pointers/directions to where to seek a solution most appreciated (I have physics background).

Comment: Is it on purpose that there is a $d v$ and no $dx$ in the first integral? The location of the $d v$ is strange as well...

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo @ArnaudMortier, fixed it. Location is just convention (it is customary in physics books - apologies for the lack of rigor - if there is such.

Comment: Nope we have different answers for that